# Use of eval when building a dict in a for loop. Name is not defined

Tags: python, dictionary, eval

Mostly curious why this syntax isn't behaving in the way I would expect it to.

Inside of a class's **init** which accepts multiple parameters (id, departmentId, active), I have the following variable:

```
attributes = [
    {'id': 5},
    {'departmentId': 10},
    {'active': True}
]
```

Essentially, I'm trying to build a dictionary where the key is the first key for each item in the attribute list, and the value is the parameter variable of that key string by getting its eval.

This works:

```
keys = [k.keys()[0] for k in attributes]
values = [eval(v) for v in keys]
vdict = {keys[i]: values[i] for i,v in enumerate(keys)}
```

However, this does not work:

```
vdict = {a.keys()[0]: eval(a.keys()[0]) for a in attributes}
```

Nor does this:

```
keys = [k.keys()[0] for k in attributes
vdict = {v: eval(v) for v in keys}
```

Doing so raises a NameError: name 'id' is not defined

I'm confused why this is the case since, to me at least, this syntax seems perfectly logical. Building a dictionary in that manor works fine when I'm doing it from two lists, not so much when I'm doing it from the attribute dictionary's key list or a list of keys.

EDIT: Python 2.7.9 on Windows if that makes any difference, here.

Comment: The expressions that don't work for you do work for me, assuming that the variables `id`, `departmentId` and `active` are defined and in scope.  If they are not defined, then I hit that `NameError`.

Comment: @jlb83 Sample code here: https://gist.github.com/Seputaes/b3f6cb12d3534720bd2c

Results in NameError: name 'departmentId' is not defined. Python 2.7.9 on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables given by the keys are not in scope inside the comprehension. If I use a loop, it works for me:

```
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self, id, departmentId, active):
        values = [
            {'id': 5},
            {'departmentId': 10},
            {'active': True}]
        vdict = {}
        for a in values:
            vdict[list(a.keys())[0]] = eval(list(a.keys())[0])
        print(vdict)

var = TestClass(1,2,False)
```

Comment: I'm running this expression inside of the class's initialization function. Using this code, same error, but it is "self" that's undefined. Very likely is a scope issue, but if so, I'm just confused why the scope changes between the examples I provided above.

Comment: How is self not defined in a constructor? Is it like def __init__(self)?

Comment: I have edited my answer, I think the problem is that the arguments are not in scope inside the comprehension.